# Check if a value is an int

Tags: go, types, type-assertion

So Im sending this payload to my app :

```
{
    "name" : "Matias Barrios",
    "age" : 123
}
```

The problem I am facing is that when I test if `name` is a string it works perfectly. But test if `age` is an int is always returning false, no matter what I do.

```
if gjson.Get(spec, "name").Exists() {
            if _, ok := gjson.Get(spec, "name").Value().(string); !ok {
                n := validator_error{Path: "_.name", Message: "should be a string"}
                errors = append(errors,n)
            }
}

if gjson.Get(spec, "age").Exists() {
            if _, ok := gjson.Get(spec, "age").Value().(int); !ok {
                n := validator_error{Path: "_.age", Message: "should be an int"}
                errors = append(errors,n)
            }

        }
```

Could someone tell me where is the error here?

Note - I am using this https://github.com/tidwall/gjson to get the values out of the JSON.

Comment: You probably should provide what library you use to get this value. Also Did you check what type it really returning maybe it returns int64/int32/uint?

Comment: https://github.com/tidwall/gjson I have added a note to what I am using. @ttomalak

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like this lib for json numbers it return float64

```
bool, for JSON booleans
float64, for JSON numbers
string, for JSON string literals
nil, for JSON null
```

Comment: Thing is If I change the line to gjson.Get(spec, "age").Value().(float64) it stops working and returns null. :(

Comment: Can you do `fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(value))` where value is `value := gjson.Get(spec, "age").Value()`

Comment: oh no. Sorry. You are right. Its working fine. Its returning null because there are no error. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As in github.com/tidwall/gjson result type can only hold float64 for json numbers.

Though you can use Int() instead of Value() to get an integer value.

```
fmt.Println(gjson.Get(spec, "age").Int())  // 123
```

Comment: It may be worth noting that a gjson result can hold large 64-bit integers, not just floating points.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `result.Type` field to check the type:

```
res := gjson.Get(spec, "age")
if res.Type != gjson.Number {
    n := validator_error{Path: "_.age", Message: "should be an int"}
}
```

If you require that the value is a whole number `123` not `123.5`:

```
res := gjson.Get(spec, "age")
if res.Type != gjson.Number || math.Floor(res.Num) != res.Num {
    n := validator_error{Path: "_.age", Message: "should be an int"}
}
```